# Excel VBA run-time error 91 using find

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I looked at a lot of questions on the site, but none seemed to be my specific problem. Everyones problem seems to be not using "set", but as you can see below I did that already.

The code is storing a year from the main sheet (well technically year -1, but same thing). And the find should look for that specific year's column on another sheet. I tried many different versions, but none seems to work (e.g. not storing the worksheet in a variable but naming it in the find function). I would like to use this variable to update a chart and the column number would help me to adjust the chart's range dynamically based on the specified year.

I know the problem is coming from referencing to another sheet, because if I simply enter the year numbers on the "main sheet" and searching there, it has no problem executing (referenced sheet is not protected - checked that as well)

```
Dim year As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet 1")
year = Worksheets("Main sheet").Cells(4, 18).Value - 1
ColNum = Cells.Find(year, ws.Range("B67"), xlValues, , xlByRows, xlNext).Column
```

Comment: `ColNum = ws.Cells.Find(...` perhaps?

Comment: @Jeeped A million thanks. It was indeed that. I can't believe I missed this. Not sure if I should delete this question or not, as it seems like I need to up my syntax game only...

Comment: Your code shouldn't be assuming that `Range.Find` will return a valid `Range` reference, which is what it does when a `.Column` member call is chained to the result - when `.Find` returns `Nothing`, you get error 91. *In this case* it was because you weren't looking on the right sheet, but in *most cases*, it's just the code assuming `Range.Find` will find what it's looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is in the referencing the other sheet indeed. When you have just `Cells` you are still referring to the current worksheet. It should be like this:

```
ColNum = ws.Cells.Find(year, ws.Range("B67"), xlValues, , xlByRows, xlNext).Column
```